# Buttons in Scroll view not displayed first button when in landscape mode in android

Tags: android, xml

In my app, the Buttons are arranged in scroll view like list view manner. it looking good when, the app in portraiture mode. when I set to in landscape mode, the first button not displayed. Thank you in advance.

```html
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/mm"

    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        >


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_milk_production"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button_layout_height"
            android:text="Milk Production"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/button_txt_size"
            android:background="@drawable/btn"
            android:textColor="#1a1a1a"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_milk_dispatch"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button_layout_height"
            android:text="Product Sales"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/button_txt_size"
            android:background="@drawable/btn"
            android:textColor="#1a1a1a"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_sale_order"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button_layout_height"
            android:text="sale order"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/button_txt_size"
            android:background="@drawable/btn"
            android:textColor="#1a1a1a"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_customer_creation"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button_layout_height"
            android:text="create customer"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/button_txt_size"
            android:background="@drawable/btn"
            android:textColor="#1a1a1a"
            />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: why you still use "fill_parent" ?

Comment: I used "match_parent". but didn't get output.

Comment: try to remove "android:layout_gravity" at the first "linear_layout"

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/background"

>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        >


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_milk_production"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Milk Production"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textColor="#1a1a1a"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_milk_dispatch"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Product Sales"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textColor="#1a1a1a"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_sale_order"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="sale order"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textColor="#1a1a1a"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_customer_creation"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="create customer"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textColor="#1a1a1a"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
     </ScrollView>
```

[image: layout output]

[image]

Comment: I tried. but didn't get correct layout in landscape mode.

Comment: @vinodhkumar IN MY IDE it is correct layout in landscape and portrait mode

Comment: do you check in emulator?

Comment: @vinodhkumar just wait i will check it. bcz it works in my android phone perfectly

Comment: @vinodhkumar check the screenshot of emulator

Answer (score 0):

remove the following from your layout

```
android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
```

This is final layout and its working perfectly for me...
(assumed height is 120dp)

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/mm"

    >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            >


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_milk_production"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:text="Milk Production"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/button_txt_size"
                android:background="@drawable/btn"
                android:textColor="#1a1a1a"
                />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_milk_dispatch"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:text="Product Sales"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/button_txt_size"
                android:background="@drawable/btn"
                android:textColor="#1a1a1a"
                />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_sale_order"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:text="sale order"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/button_txt_size"
                android:background="@drawable/btn"
                android:textColor="#1a1a1a"
                />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_customer_creation"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:text="create customer"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/button_txt_size"
                android:background="@drawable/btn"
                android:textColor="#1a1a1a"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/mm"

    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"  <<-- remove this line
        >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        >


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_milk_production"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button_layout_height"
            android:text="Milk Production"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/button_txt_size"
            android:background="@drawable/btn"
            android:textColor="#1a1a1a"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_milk_dispatch"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button_layout_height"
            android:text="Product Sales"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/button_txt_size"
            android:background="@drawable/btn"
            android:textColor="#1a1a1a"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_sale_order"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button_layout_height"
            android:text="sale order"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/button_txt_size"
            android:background="@drawable/btn"
            android:textColor="#1a1a1a"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_customer_creation"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button_layout_height"
            android:text="create customer"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/button_txt_size"
            android:background="@drawable/btn"
            android:textColor="#1a1a1a"
            />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove one LinearLayout tag from layout. It's redundant in your case.

```
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/mm">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_milk_production"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_layout_height"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn"
        android:text="Milk Production"
        android:textColor="#1a1a1a"
        android:textSize="@dimen/button_txt_size" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_milk_dispatch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_layout_height"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn"
        android:text="Product Sales"
        android:textColor="#1a1a1a"
        android:textSize="@dimen/button_txt_size" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_sale_order"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_layout_height"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn"
        android:text="sale order"
        android:textColor="#1a1a1a"
        android:textSize="@dimen/button_txt_size" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_customer_creation"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_layout_height"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn"
        android:text="create customer"
        android:textColor="#1a1a1a"
        android:textSize="@dimen/button_txt_size" />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this...

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_milk_production"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:text="Milk Production"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:textColor="#1a1a1a"
                />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_sale_order"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:text="sale order"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:textColor="#1a1a1a"
                />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_milk_dispatch"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:text="Product Sales"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:textColor="#1a1a1a"
                />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_customer_creation"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:text="create customer"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:textColor="#1a1a1a"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```